# Python and efficient looping of set intersections (using trees)

Tags: python, tree

Below are the distinct paths of attributes and values of a decision tree.  If I were to enumerate the tree of every combination, the tree would be huge. So...each path of the tree are all of the distinct attributes and values of leaf node.

If given a list of values to score, i.e find the the node with the most common elements, I use the below code.

What is the most insanely fast method of trying to accomplish what I want?  The below works but time is of the up-most important so much so that is worthy of using `c` and importing into python.

Would a tree structure be faster?  If so - what structure?  would scipy weave be faster?

```
nodes = {}
nodes[1] = ['hod=1','hod=2','state=NY','state=LA']
nodes[2] = ['hod=3','hod=4','state=FL','state=NV']
nodes[3] = ['hod=5','hod=6','state=WY','state=HI']
nodes[4] = ['hod=5','hod=6']


score = ['hod=6','state=WY','dow=4']
score_size = len(score)

max_node = -1
max_len = -1
for node_id, node in nodes.iteritems():
    this_node_interection_len = len(set(score).intersection(node))
    if this_node_interection_len>max_len:
        max_len = this_node_interection_len
        max_node = node_id   
    #print node_id, len(set(score).intersection(node))


print 'max_node',3
```

Comment: You should probably make the node values sets rather than lists, and make `score` a set to begin with rather than making a new set from it for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *might* be faster to store the data in a heap, where `len(score.intersection(node))` is key value for each node. This way, building the initial data structure would be a bit slower than making a flat dictionary would be, but you could quickly retrieve the top several nodes rather than just the node with the maximum score.

You should also look into using PyPy or something similar to optimize performance.

Comment: Yes.I would use PyPy but web server uses uwsgi and gevent.  cant use pypy.  I am doing this for ever web request.

Comment: I added blist and using sorted sets rather than the default list

Comment: What did you use `blist` for? Did you change the type of `nodes` to `blist`?

Comment: I used the sorted sets so intersections are done on sets already sorted. I wlll have a long set for each node.  Also there will multiple nodes I have to score.  I might have to give up Cython and uwsgi with gevent loop in favour of pypy with tornado.

Comment: I seriously doubt that finding intersections is faster on sorted sets; if anything, it's probably slower. `set` uses hashing to determine "where" an item is, so it's actually extremely efficient at finding intersections.